# Node.js Sass version 7.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sass

I used Node.js v16.13.1 and created a React application. I tried to use [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29), but when I tried to run it, I got this error:

> Node Sass version 7.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0

Comment: So? What's your question? Looks like Node Sass version 7.0.0 is incompatible with the node version you're running

Comment: Yes, you right @Dominik, I only change by sass.

Comment: i get the same error if I am on Node 16. It complains 7.0.0 is not compatible with 4.0.0. But I am not running 4!!!! I am running 16!!!!

Comment: @OliverWatkins It is npm version. Not node version. You can check nmp version with npm -v

Comment: Which version of react-scripts are you using? This could be a dependency issue and nothing to do with the node version.

Answer (score 298):

If you want to use [SCSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) and [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) in your React app, try to do as below and your files will be correctly compiled:

1. First remove `node-sass`:

> ```bash
> yarn remove node-sass
> # if you use npm
> npm uninstall node-sass
> ```

2. Then install `sass` instead of `node-sass`:

> ```bash
> yarn add -D sass
> # if you use npm
> npm i -D sass
> ```

Comment: I'm using the same version of node, and create-react-app but I'm still getting an error like: To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass.
Run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace.

Comment: Great solution. It is also mentioned here in the docs now I see: 

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet

Comment: This solution works for me, but after removing the node_modules and package-lock.json file and finally running `npm install` .

Comment: Just to add then some use might need to update webpack.config.js file
`
"css-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            implementation: require("sass")
                        }
                    }`

Comment: what is `-D` means in here?

Comment: @RakisFriski -D is a shortcut for --save-dev and adds the dependency in "devDependencies"

Answer (score 147):

## Don't use node-sass anymore

`node-sass` is deprecated. Instead use `sass`. You can uninstall the old and install the new one:

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

#### But if you still prefer to use `node-sass`

You can use the following table to install the appropriate version `node-sass` for your installed Node.js version which you can check by the command `node --version`.

```
npm install node-sass@(your version)
```

[image: versions]

Comment: This solution worked for me. should be accepted as the answer. node-sass deprecated in the new version of Node

Comment: I did this first actually because my other project works well with just sass but when I created a new project using typescript template, im now getting the op's error. Any advice?

Comment: @JkAlombro You may need to check the node version using `node --version` and install a specific version based on the table. It's only on version mismatch that the op's error occurs

Answer (score 20):

You can just switch to Sass in your *package.json* file, like so:

```
 "node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.49.9",
```

This way, React still asks for `node-sass` after removing it and replacing with `sass`, so you can alias it like this and now React will use Sass.

Comment: Wow, great solution, thanks!, many components use deprecated dependency to node-sass, It is the better clean solution.

Comment: this fixed it on node 16.17.0 react@18.2.0 and react-scripts@2.1.3 for me. Thank you

Comment: out of all the options, this is the only one that works, thank you

Comment: After spending upwards of 6 hrs installing and re-installing node-sass/sass, this is the only thing that worked. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem with `sass`, and I ran these commands like below, but none of them worked.

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

So finally I took a look at my `package.json` and I saw that I installed *sass-loader*, so I uninstalled and installed that and the problem was fixed. You can use the commands below for that:

```
npm uninstall sass-loader
npm install sass-loader
```

Comment: yes the loader is the problem, when you remove the node-sass to switch to the sass you must remove the loader of the node-sass too, otherwise it will give you problem forever

Answer (score 11):

I figured out this issue using `node-sass` version `4.14.1` with the following commands:

- With npm

> ```bash
> npm uninstall node-sass
> npm install node-sass@4.14.1
> ```

- With yarn

> ```
> yarn remove node-sass
> yarn add node-sass@4.14.1
> ```

Comment: but why node-sass 4.14.1 when node is version 16? I am so confused.

Comment: Hi Oliver, it is not the version of node, it is the version of the npm package node-sass

Answer (score 11):

Just remove the `node-sass` and install `sass` instead:

1. delete the [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) directory.
2. run `yarn remove node-sass`
3. run `yarn add sass`

Or with npm

1. delete node_modules directory.
2. run `npm uninstall --save node-sass`
3. run `npm install --save sass`

Answer (score 8):

There is a lot of misinformation in the replies to this question and it's the first thing to shows up in Google:

If you see this problem in your application, the culprit is *not* the `node-sass` or Node.js version. It's the `sass-loader` issue and that's the library you need to upgrade since older versions are not compatible with the newer `node-sass`.

Comment: Is there only one sass-loader issue? If so, what does it refer to?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do `npm install node-sass@6.0`.

This is because Node.js 16 is compatible with node-sass version 6.0.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue. At the time of installing 'node-sass', my Node.js version was 15.

After downgrading to Node.js version 12 and installing the version 12-related '[node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)', it worked fine.

```
node -v

# Output: v15.2.0

nvm use 12.18.3
```

Now using Node.js v12.18.3 (npm v6.14.6)

```
node -v

# Output: v12.8.3

npm install node-sass@4.14.1
```

To make sure it's working properly, add some *abc.sass* file. And write styles and import it in the component.

Answer (score 0):

Based on input and the following steps, I got it working for shopware6 while *build-administration.sh* where a similar error occurred:

**Error: Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.**

```
ERROR in ./src/app/component/base/sw-button/sw-button.scss (./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/app/component/base/sw-button/sw-button.sc)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
    at getRenderFuncFromSassImpl (/var/ww
```

Checking the currently installed node-sass version and uninstalling and installing the "lower" version:

```
npx node-sass -v results in:
node-sass: 7.0.1
libsass 3.5.5

npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass@4.14.1

npx node-sass -v results in:
node-sass       4.14.1  (Wrapper)       [JavaScript]
libsass         3.5.5   (Sass Compiler) [C/C++]
```

Before that, I checked the mentioned version numbers in a complete *htdocs* folder:

```
.../htdocs$ find . -iname '*package.json*'  | xargs  grep node-sass {}
```

In the resulting (huge) list, the following node-sass versions are found:

```
....nistration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/node-sass/package.json:    "lint": "eslint bin/node-sass lib scripts test",
./vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/sass-loader/package.json:    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
grep: {}: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
./vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/stylelint-webpack-plugin/package.json:    "node-sass",
./vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/build/nuxt-component-library/package.json:        "node-sass": "4.12.0",
./vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/package.json:    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",    <<<<<< THIS ONE !!
./vendor/shopware/administration/Resources/app/administration/package.jsonORIG-2021-12-29:    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
```

After uninstalling and install node-sass@4.14.1 and changing the marked line from

```
"node-sass": "^7.0.1",
```

to

```
"node-sass": "^4.0.1",
```

it compiled and *build-administration.sh* (a shopware6 thing...) succeeded.

```
Time: 58913ms
Entrypoint commons = static/js/runtime.js static/css/vendors-node.css static/js/vendors-node.js static/js/vendors-node.js.map static/js/commons.js
Entrypoint app = static/js/runtime.js static/css/vendors-node.css static/js/vendors-node.js static/js/vendors-node.js.map static/css/app.css static/js/app.js
Entrypoint storefront = static/js/runtime.js static/css/vendors-node.css static/js/vendors-node.js static/js/vendors-node.js.map static/css/storefront.css static/js/storefront.js
Entrypoint payone-payment = static/js/runtime.js static/css/vendors-node.css static/js/vendors-node.js static/js/vendors-node.js.map static/css/payone-payment.css static/js/payone-payment.js
Entrypoint wbm-tag-manager-ecomm = static/js/runtime.js static/css/vendors-node.css static/js/vendors-node.js static/js/vendors-node.js.map static/css/wbm-tag-manager-ecomm.css static/js/wbm-tag-manager-ecomm.js
   3909 modules
build-administration.sh: 14: build-administration.sh: [[: not found
Copying files for bundle: FrameworkBundle
Copying files for bundle: MonologBundle
Copying files for bundle: SwiftmailerBundle
Copying files for bundle: SensioFrameworkExtraBundle
Copying files for bundle: TwigBundle
Copying files for bundle: EnqueueBundle
Copying files for bundle: EnqueueAdapterBundle
Copying files for bundle: Framework
Copying files for bundle: System
Copying files for bundle: Content
Copying files for bundle: Checkout
Copying files for bundle: Administration
Copying files for bundle: Storefront
Copying files for bundle: Elasticsearch
Copying files for bundle: SwagPlatformDemoData
Copying files for bundle: Netzp6AddressValidator
Copying files for bundle: PayonePayment
Copying files for bundle: WbmTagManagerEcomm
Copying files for bundle: DbalKernelPluginLoader


 [OK] Successfully copied all bundle files
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case
#first uninstalled using npm
npm uninstall node-sass
Then install
#using npm
npm i -D sass

Answer (score 0):

**Removing *yarn.lock*** and regenerating it solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

I got this error two months back. I tried each and every solution I can probably find.

Check whether you have created multiple React projects on the desktop. I did the same and started facing this issue. Combine all of them inside a single folder to get rid of the error. It worked for me. Please try this if you are making the same mistake.