# Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, sass, yarnpkg

I can't run `yarn start` in the terminal to start my react project.

I tried this, and many other things that most people recommend, but it does nothing:

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add sass
```

```
yarn run v1.22.17

  ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!../node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./assets/stylesheets/application.scss 39 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]
./src/index.jsx 396 bytes [built] [code generated]

ERROR in ./assets/stylesheets/application.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!../node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./assets/stylesheets/application.scss)
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
    at getRenderFuncFromSassImpl (/Users/blaisepop/code/blaisepop/react-giphy/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:108:19)
    at Object.sassLoader (/Users/blaisep/code/blaisepop/react-giphy/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:46:20)
 @ ./assets/stylesheets/application.scss 2:14-132 21:1-42:3 22:19-137
 @ ./src/index.jsx 3:0-48

webpack 5.72.0 compiled with 1 error in 1583 ms
```

Comment: What is your version of `sass-loader`?

Comment: Indeed it was a sass-loader issue. I deleted it and re-installed it and it now works!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js Sass version 7.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70281346/node-js-sass-version-7-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0-5-0-0-6-0-0)

Comment: Yes, I did what I mentionned in my previous comment and it worked well.

Comment: Yes but we should mark this question as duplicate. =)

Answer (score 3):

## Don't use node-sass anymore

`node-sass` is deprecated. Instead use `sass`.

Use the following command to uninstall `node-sass` and install the new version

```
npm uninstall node-sass

npm install sass
```

**But if you want to keep using `node-sass` for some reason,**

You can use the following table to install the appropriate version `node-sass` for your installed node version which you can check by the command `node --version`

```
npm install node-sass@(your version)
```

[image]