# sass installation not working in React bootstrap

Tags: reactjs

I am using react bootstrap

Want to customize reactbootstrap theme , so followed these instructions

```
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/
```

So I installed sass , but it still giving error to install node-sass ( which is deprecated) as in the

any idea what i am doing wrong

[image: screenshot]

[image: error with node-sass]

Comment: the prerequisite is node-sass which is different from sass. You will need to include node-sass, using code [npm install node-sass]

Comment: i did npm install sass , as in the above tutorial

Comment: just install node-sass

Comment: @JacksonQuintero node-sass giving compatibility error , whereas node verions match i think (screenshot attached)

Comment: similar to this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70281346/node-js-sass-version-7-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0-5-0-0-6-0-0

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your node_modules folder, lock file and replacing 'node-sass' with 'sass'

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm uninstall node-sass
npm i -S sass
npm i
```